# Create user in LDAP, authentication failed

Tags: php, windows, ldap

When creating the user I cannot start the section with the user's password. The user is created, but when testing the connection, it marks invalid credentials. Can you tell me where I am wrong? How should the password be encrypted?

````
$ds = '192.168.1.10'; 
$portldap = 389; 
$ldap_username = 'CN=Administrador,CN=Users,DC=Local,DC=com';
$ldap_password = 'rootadm1';
$ldap_password_user = $ldap_password;

$ldap_connection = ldap_connect($ds, $portldap);
if($ldap_connection ){
    // We have to set this option for the version of Active Directory we are using.
    ldap_set_option($ldap_connection, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3) or die('Unable to set LDAP protocol version');
    ldap_set_option($ldap_connection, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0); // We need this for doing an LDAP search.

    $r = ldap_bind($ldap_connection, $ldap_username, $ldap_password);
    if($r === TRUE){
        $CN = htmlspecialchars($_POST["cn"]);
        $ldaprecord['cn'] =  $CN;
        $ldaprecord['sAMAccountName'] = $_POST["sAMAccountName"]; //20caract
        $ldaprecord['userPrincipalName'] = $_POST["userprincipalname"];
        $ldaprecord["objectClass"][0] = "top";
        $ldaprecord["objectClass"][1] = "person";
        $ldaprecord["objectClass"][2] = "organizationalPerson";
        $ldaprecord["objectClass"][3] = "user";
        $ldaprecord['description']= $_POST["description"]; 
        $ldaprecord["userAccountControl"][0] = "66656"; 
        
        $ldap_new = 'CN='.$CN.',CN=Users,DC=Local,DC=com';

        $result = ldap_add($ldap_connection, $ldap_new, $ldaprecord);        
        if($result) {  
            //Success creating user - Add password
            $addPrecord['userPassword'] = '{MD5}' . base64_encode(pack('H*',md5($ldap_password_user)));
            //$addPrecord["unicodePwd"][0] = iconv( 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16LE', $ldap_password_user );
            $add_record=  ldap_modify($ldap_connection, $ldap_new, $addPrecord);
            if($add_record){
                ldap_close($ldap_connection);
                return $result;
            }
            else {
                echo "LDAP Error: ".ldap_error($ldap_connection)."\n";
                exit;
            }
        }
        else {
                echo "LDAP Error: ".ldap_error($ldap_connection)."\n";
                exit;
        }
    }
}
else {
     echo "cannot connect to LDAP server at $ds.";
} ```
[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOzqZ.png
````

Comment: Does your server use MD5 for passwords? Maybe try [SHA](https://gist.github.com/mattrude/657334/98d7c111796db51059a5fd788240fd69672b8daf#file-changepassword-php-L62)?

Comment: how do i check it? cómo lo verifico? @ChrisHaas

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.